# AWS codebuild not support openjdk14?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I can not figure out how to make aws code build to support openjdk14, can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenJDK 14 is already not supported (ended in September 2020). Use either Java 8 or Java 11. Anything else is experimental until Java 17 (September 2021). Don't expect AWS to support an environment with a lifetime of 6 months.

See [Java version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) for some details.  It doesn't copy and paste very well but for JDK 14:

> Java SE 14    Release: March 2020     End of Support: September 2020 for
> OpenJDK